# How to emplace object without constructor arguments to STL constainer?

Tags: c++, stl, containers, emplace

Suppose I have an class that has constructor taking no arguments, and an STL container of its objects: `list<Object> lst;` Is there a way to insert a new object in-place?

I know something like `lst.push_back(Object());` is going to work, equally fast as it would use move constructor, however it seems a little bit odd that there is no function to simply create new object at the end of the list without any arguments, while there already is emplace that could fit that place.

Could you please, provide some explanation if it isn't actually possible?

Comment: Did you try [`std::vector::emplace_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, [`emplace_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/emplace_back) does exactly that.

Just use `lst.emplace_back();` and that function will create an object in place at the end of the list.

Comment: Thanks, it works. That was my first intuition however KDevelop suggested to make it `lst.emplace_back<Object>();` which for some reason didn't work. It's embarasing that among many versions I've tried wasn't this simpliest one. Btw. any idea why explicit type version didn't work?

Comment: @pkubik That's a strange suggestion, because `emplace_back` is a variadic template only parameterized by the constructor arguments. So obviously this shouldn't work unless you have a constructor that takes an `Object` as its only argument.

Comment: That shouldn't make sense anyway to have to specify the type of the object to be constructed. This type is known as soon as you've declare the list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use
`lst.emplace_back();`